# Getting an error in jupyter notebook while running my code

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

MY CODE :-

## Read the census data into a Pandas DataFrame*

```
file_path = Path("sfo_neighborhoods_census_data.csv") 
sfo_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col="year") 
sfo_data.head()
```

ERROR :-

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 # Read the census data into a Pandas DataFrame
2 file_path = Path("sfo_neighborhoods_census_data.csv")
----> 3 sfo_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col="year")
4 sfo_data.head()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sfo_neighborhoods_census_data.csv'

Comment: Looks like the file `sfo_neighborhoods_census_data.csv` can't be found in the directory you are looking for it. Post a snippet of your code that returns the error you've posted.

Comment: # Read the census data into a Pandas DataFrame                                                                                                      
file_path = Path("sfo_neighborhoods_census_data.csv")
sfo_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col="year")
sfo_data.head()

Comment: You don't need to copy full error. You can delete it to make your post more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your file destination. you should make sure that put it in the same directory where your python code saves.

if you use **google colab**, you can upload your file in google drive, then mounting the google drive. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate ? couldn't understand . I am Not sure where my python code saves. I am beginner..learning python for data analytics and just started using jupyter notebook. I tried to save my csv files in the same folder where my .ipynb file is stored. But receiving the same error.

Comment: Try a different path as well.